# Loop through cells to send email

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Hello I have a macro that is supposed to send emails to the addresses on my C Column with copy to the email addresses in the F column and some text... But my problem is that it is not looping through each name and just goes to the last one... Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
Sub Send_Email()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String
Dim cel As Range

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

For Each cel In Range(("C2"), Range("C2").End(xlDown))

    strbody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "My name Is William" & vbNewLine & _
            "I work at Fair" & vbNewLine & _
            "Bye" & vbNewLine & _
            "WH"

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = cel.Value    '"email.address@fair.com"
        .CC = cel.Offset(0, 3).Value & "Ivan.Martinez@fair.com"
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Information You Requested"
        .Body = strbody
        .Display
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        '.Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
Next cel

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: After the line `For Each cel In Range(("C2"), Range("C2").End(xlDown))` Add `Debug.Print Range(("C2"), Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Address` to see if the range you're looping through is the range you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your code:

```
Dim lastRow As Long  
Dim Rng As Range  

lastRow = Range("C:C").Find("*", Range("C1"), Searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Set Rng = Range(Cells(2,"C"),Cells(lastRow,"C"))

For Each Cel in Rng

'The rest of your code goes here.
```

This is a little more robust way of setting your range.

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each cel In Range(("C2"), Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Cells
```